# Highlight column values when difference is greater than a specific value

Tags: vimrc

File sample:

```
abc xyz aca sdasda 2.4 rn 3.4
abc xyz acs sd3sa 2.4 rn 3.1
abc xyz acs s12 2.1 rn 3.2
```

What Im trying to achieve here is if diff of values (ex: `3.4` and `2.4`) is equal to or greater than `1.0` ,then both value should highlight.
Above output should happen by default when I open a specific file (ex: `file_output12` ).

```
vim version: 7.4
system:Centos 6.8
```

Comment: Are you sure you have Vim version 1.7.629? On one of Vim's FTPs I found Vim version 3.0 from 1996, and Centos 6.8 isn't so old.

Comment: @ grodzik my bad ,version is 7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    function! HighlightDiff(match1, match2)
        let a=str2float(a:match1)
        let b=str2float(a:match2)
        if abs(a-b) >= 1.0
            call add(w:matchid, matchaddpos('WarningMsg', [[line('.'), col('.'), strlen(a:match1)]]))
            call add(w:matchid, matchaddpos('WarningMsg', [[line('.'), col('.')+strlen(a:match1) + 4, strlen(a:match2)]]))
        endif
    endfunction

    function! HighlightMatches()
        " ignore non-existing highlighting ids
        sil! call map(get(w:, 'matchid', []), 'matchdelete(v:val)')
        let w:matchid = []
        :%s/\(\d\+\%(\.\d\+\)\?\) rn \(\d\+\%(\.\d\+\)\?\)/\=HighlightDiff(submatch(1), submatch(2))/gn
    endfunction

    com! HighlightDiff :call HighlightMatches()
```

It uses a regular expression to find numbers optionally followed by `.` and more numbers, followed by `rn` followed again by numbers with an optional dot. It remembers the position of the two matches and uses `matchaddpos()` to highlight those positions if both numbers are greater than `1.0` apart. However, since we do not know exactly know, the position of the second match, we have do to some calculation from the first number to the second number (therefore I assume, that `rn` must always be 1 space followed by rn followed by 1 space).

It uses a `:%s/../\=function/gn` to perform the highlight. It means, that it actually runs a search/replace command, however because of the `n` flag, it won't replace anything, just call the function with the match.

All of this depends on the following version:
Vim 7.4 compiled with float support, support for evaluating the expression even when using the `n` flag ([patch 7.3.627](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.3.627)), and [matchaddpos](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.330)